# Animation on custom layout that was added to WindowManager

Tags: android

I want to add animation to custom view but cant add. my code is

```
    private WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, desiredCallerIdHeight, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    //params.flags=WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED;
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 0;
    params.windowAnimations=R.anim.slide;
    baseCallerIdView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_caller_id_view, null);
```

and in `touchListener()` i am trying to dismiss the view if you swipe

```
    Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,R.anim.slide);
    baseCallerIdView.startAnimation(animation1);
    animation1.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation1)
                                {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation1)
                                {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation1)
                                {
                                    removeCallerIdViewFromWindow();

                                }
                            });
```

any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To animate layouts in WindowManager, you'll need to use a `ValueAnimator` and animate the parameters directly, like in this snippet:

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1.0f);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        float percent = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        params.x = percent * screenWidth;
        params.y = percent * screenHeight;
        mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(baseCallerIdView, params);
    }
});
```

You can't use a normal animator due to limitations of adding views directly like this.